# Collision detection not working for adding 1 to score

Tags: swift, collision, detection, contacts

Hey guys im having a big problem with collision detection, it seems that the ship is able to collide correctly with the objectGroup and the missileGroup. The problem is that i wanted that when the missile passed the wall node then it will add 1 to the score but it isnt working, I have tried to fix it for more than 5 hours and yet not finding any solution.

```
class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var spaceShip = SKSpriteNode ()
var bgSpace = SKSpriteNode ()

var score = 0
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()
var labelHolder = SKSpriteNode()


let shipGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 1
let objectGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 2
let wallGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 3
let missileGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 4

var gameOver = 0

var movingObjects = SKNode()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */

self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5)
self.addChild(movingObjects)

makeBackground()

self.addChild(labelHolder)

scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
scoreLabel.text = "0"
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),        self.frame.size.height - 150)
scoreLabel.zPosition = 1000
self.addChild(scoreLabel)

//add spaceship

var spaceShipTexture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "productImgs/F5S4.png")
spaceShip = SKSpriteNode (texture: spaceShipTexture)
spaceShip.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 3, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
spaceShip.xScale = 0.7
spaceShip.yScale = 0.7

spaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(spaceShip.frame.size.width, spaceShip.frame.size.height))

spaceShip.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
spaceShip.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
spaceShip.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = shipGroup
spaceShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = objectGroup | missileGroup

spaceShip.zPosition = 10

self.addChild(spaceShip)



//add ground

let ground = SKNode()
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake (self.frame.size.width * 2, 250)) //180
ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shipGroup

self.addChild(ground)

//add top

let top = SKNode()
top.position = CGPointMake(0, 1180)
top.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake (self.frame.size.width * 2, 1200)) // 1000
top.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
top.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
top.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shipGroup

self.addChild(top)



var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("makeMissile"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

// this is the wall on the left... enable skView.showsPhysics = true in viewcontroller 
var wall = SKNode()
wall.position = CGPoint(x:10 , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(3, self.frame.size.height))

wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallGroup
wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = missileGroup
wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
self.addChild(wall)



}

 func makeBackground(){
 //add bg

if gameOver == 0 {

var bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "productImgs/1820925.jpg")

var backgroundAnimated = SKAction.moveByX(-bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 12)
var replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
var backgroundMoveForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([backgroundAnimated,replaceBackground]))

for var i:CGFloat=0; i<3; i++ {

    bgSpace = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    bgSpace.position = CGPoint (x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/2 + bgTexture.size().width * i, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    bgSpace.size.height = self.frame.height
    bgSpace.runAction(backgroundMoveForever)
    movingObjects.addChild(bgSpace)

    //check this part needed

}

}


}

func makeMissile(){

if gameOver == 0 {


         var missile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "productImgs/missile-hi.png")
    missile.setScale(0.38)

    // Adding SpriteKit physics body for collision detection
    missile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(missile.frame.size.width,missile.frame.size.height))
    missile.physicsBody?.dynamic = false



    missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = missileGroup
    missile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = shipGroup
    missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shipGroup | wallGroup



    missile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    missile.name = "missile"


    // Selecting random y position for missile
    var random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.height)) + 1

var randomPosition = CGFloat(random)
    missile.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + 20, randomPosition)


    var movementAmount = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 2))

    var moveMissile = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width * 5, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.width / 100))
    var removeMissile = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    var moveAndRemoveMissile = SKAction.sequence([moveMissile, removeMissile])

    missile.runAction(moveAndRemoveMissile)

    movingObjects.addChild(missile)

    //add wall



} else if gameOver == 0 {
    gameOver = 1
    movingObjects.speed = 0
    gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    gameOverLabel.fontSize = 40
    gameOverLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    gameOverLabel.zPosition = 100000
    labelHolder.addChild(gameOverLabel)
}

}

// part for adding score not working

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == wallGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == wallGroup {
    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}
else if gameOver == 0 {

        gameOver = 1

        movingObjects.speed = 0

        gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
        gameOverLabel.fontSize = 30
        gameOverLabel.text = "Game Over! Tap to play again."
        gameOverLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        labelHolder.addChild(gameOverLabel)

    }


}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
/* Called when a touch begins */

if (gameOver == 0) {
    spaceShip.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    spaceShip.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 300))
} else {
    score = 0
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    movingObjects.removeAllChildren()

    makeBackground()

    spaceShip.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 3, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    spaceShip.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    labelHolder.removeAllChildren()
    gameOver = 0
    movingObjects.speed = 1


}

}
```

Comment: In `didBeginContact`,I don;t understand by `if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == wallGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == wallGroup`

Comment: Yea I didnt as well... im new to these and what i tried to say there was that if bodaA (missile) made contact with bodyB (the wall) then it would add 1 to the score but it seems that the wall nor the missile detect each other i dont know.

Comment: So,there is the problem,if you do the if line right,is gonna work

Comment: Is there a way to fix this? I didnt quite understand that contact.BodyA.category.... statements and have been trying to find a way to understand them to fix that but I have failed

Comment: Now ,I'm making an answer

Comment: I need to know whats the wall in the lef,check the answer

Comment: the wall in the left is the wall node after the missile timer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stupid your collisions correct,delete in `didBeginContact` the if ,else if.It should work.I don't know what you mean by`workspaceShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = objectGroup | missileGroup`.Set `workspaceShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2` to make sure thats working.

***Edit***

```
class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var spaceShip = SKSpriteNode ()
var bgSpace = SKSpriteNode ()
var wall = SKNode()

var score = 0
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()
var labelHolder = SKSpriteNode()


let shipGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 1
let objectGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 2
let wallGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 3
let missileGroup:UInt32 = 1 << 4

var gameOver = 0

var movingObjects = SKNode()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */

self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5)
self.addChild(movingObjects)

makeBackground()

self.addChild(labelHolder)

scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
scoreLabel.text = "0"
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),        self.frame.size.height - 150)
scoreLabel.zPosition = 1000
self.addChild(scoreLabel)

//add spaceship

var spaceShipTexture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "productImgs/F5S4.png")
spaceShip = SKSpriteNode (texture: spaceShipTexture)
spaceShip.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 3, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
spaceShip.xScale = 0.7
spaceShip.yScale = 0.7

spaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(spaceShip.frame.size.width, spaceShip.frame.size.height))

spaceShip.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
spaceShip.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
spaceShip.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = shipGroup
spaceShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = objectGroup | missileGroup

spaceShip.zPosition = 10

self.addChild(spaceShip)



//add ground

let ground = SKNode()
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake (self.frame.size.width * 2, 250)) //180
ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shipGroup

self.addChild(ground)

//add top

let top = SKNode()
top.position = CGPointMake(0, 1180)
top.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake (self.frame.size.width * 2, 1200)) // 1000
top.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
top.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
top.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shipGroup

self.addChild(top)



var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("makeMissile"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



wall.position = CGPoint(x:10 , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(3, self.frame.size.height))

wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallGroup
wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = missileGroup
wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
self.addChild(wall)



}

 func makeBackground(){
 //add bg

if gameOver == 0 {

var bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "productImgs/1820925.jpg")

var backgroundAnimated = SKAction.moveByX(-bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 12)
var replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
var backgroundMoveForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([backgroundAnimated,replaceBackground]))

for var i:CGFloat=0; i<3; i++ {

    bgSpace = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    bgSpace.position = CGPoint (x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/2 + bgTexture.size().width * i, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    bgSpace.size.height = self.frame.height
    bgSpace.runAction(backgroundMoveForever)
    movingObjects.addChild(bgSpace)

    //check this part needed

}

}


}

func makeMissile(){

if gameOver == 0 {


         var missile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "productImgs/missile-hi.png")
    missile.setScale(0.38)

    // Adding SpriteKit physics body for collision detection
    missile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(missile.frame.size.width,missile.frame.size.height))
    missile.physicsBody?.dynamic = false



    missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = missileGroup
    missile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = shipGroup
    missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shipGroup | wallGroup



    missile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    missile.name = "missile"


    // Selecting random y position for missile
    var random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.height)) + 1

var randomPosition = CGFloat(random)
    missile.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + 20, randomPosition)


    var movementAmount = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 2))

    var moveMissile = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width * 5, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.width / 100))
    var removeMissile = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    var moveAndRemoveMissile = SKAction.sequence([moveMissile, removeMissile])

    missile.runAction(moveAndRemoveMissile)

    movingObjects.addChild(missile)

    //add wall
 if wall.position.x < missile.position.x{
            score++
            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        }


} else if gameOver == 0 {
    gameOver = 1
    movingObjects.speed = 0
    gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    gameOverLabel.fontSize = 40
    gameOverLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    gameOverLabel.zPosition = 100000
    labelHolder.addChild(gameOverLabel)
}

}

// part for adding score not working

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == wallGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == wallGroup {
    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}
else if gameOver == 0 {

        gameOver = 1

        movingObjects.speed = 0

        gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
        gameOverLabel.fontSize = 30
        gameOverLabel.text = "Game Over! Tap to play again."
        gameOverLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        labelHolder.addChild(gameOverLabel)

    }


}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
/* Called when a touch begins */

if (gameOver == 0) {
    spaceShip.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    spaceShip.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 300))
} else {
    score = 0
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    movingObjects.removeAllChildren()

    makeBackground()

    spaceShip.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 3, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    spaceShip.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    labelHolder.removeAllChildren()
    gameOver = 0
    movingObjects.speed = 1


}

}
```

It kinda works,but it adds 1 from the start,because I can't figured out .Who is the wall in the left

Comment: why would i delete the if,else if ... theres no way to edit the score then, there are many types of contact in ship sprite .... I wanted to add 1 to score once the contact between missile and wall is detected. Sorry to bother you, but if you want i can put my code in a github and link it in here.

Comment: @Darkboss,yes put it on github. Try first 'if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == wallGroup'.If bodyA is the ship .And ' let wallGroup:UInt32 = 3' to be clear

Comment: @Darkboss First of all why there are lot of images outside the images.xcassets,and are duplicates in different folders

Comment: yea sorry i was testing different images... and as i told you i am really new to this , sorry

Comment: @Darkboss.Beacuse of the image and the speed of github,still i don't have the project

Comment: sorry for that... im stuck at this and this is part of some IB thing i need to hand in ... im desperate at this moment because ive been for 3 days trying to work this out... please help me

Comment: Scoart Thank you a lot , I guess the didmakecontact part didnt work but instead you added some lines that added 1 to score with missiles position ... sorry if i didnt clear it out in my code but the wall was that part in gamscene after the missile timer...